# NodeJS Writable stream debounce

Tags: node.js, mongodb, stream, timeout, debouncing

I have recently implemented a writeable stream that persists aggregate data from multiple readable streams to a mongo database. Due to the high throughput of the streams I'm looking to implement some debounce functionality.

I am struggling to pin down a good method of doing this, the trouble arrises from the need to apply back-pressure in the pipeline. Essentially, if the debounce timeout executes, the Writeable 'next()' callback needs to be called only once the timeout function is completed but if the timeout has not yet executed, the Writeable needs to 'next()' immediately to maintain the flow.

I feel like I'm missing something simple here and hopefully someone here can make me kick myself.

**_write() logic explanation/TLDR:**

```
// Queues a mongo bulk upsert operation.
queueMongoUpsertOperation(someData);

// This should only be called NOW if the timeout isn't executing
// as we should wait for it to finish the save before reading
// more data IF it is saving.
// Best/SAFEST way to block this call when the timeout is executing
next()

// Simple debounce.
clearTimeout(timeout);

timeout = setTimeout(function(){

    // Execute the actual asyncronous save from the queued upsert operations.
    executeMongoBulkUpsert(function(){

        // Because the next() above is somehow blocked when the timeout
        // is executed, we should now called next() from within
        // the debounced function.
        next();

    });

}, 1000);
```

Comment: It seems no one can offer advice, since this post the scope of my project has changed slightly but I will be sure to come back here and offer an answer if I get around to implementing this logic.